# Apache2+Wordpress, not displaying the index.php but download

Tags: apache, wordpress

I just moved my Wordpress site from using nginx to Apache2, and found that the homepage could not be shown, instead, the browser prompt me to download it (the file download is exactly the one of index.php).

However, the strange thing is that, except the home page, all other pages (including the individual post page, wp-admin pages, rss, theme preview, etc.) work fine.

And i have another wordpress site hosted in the same machine, works fine.

Here is the .htaccess file: (this is actually what Wordpress did)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```

And here is what i got from the access.log

```
207.46.92.16 - - [30/Dec/2010:16:17:56 +0800] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506; SLCC1; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)"
```

Actually I did the following but no change:

1. Disable mod_rewrite Copy the
2. .htaccess from the correct wordpress
       site

Did anyone face anything like this or have any clue on this?

I also opens a link here. try the followings:

1. http://www.weigblog.com/
2. adding index.php (sorry i can't post more than 1 link)
3. adding testphp.php

Comment: What does the downloaded file contain?

Comment: The content of the downloaded file is the same with the index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one thing is for certain, the htaccess file has nothing to do with it.

Is it, maybe, possible that your server is unaware that PHP is an actual application? If you don't have the handlers setup (`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`) or the PHP module isn't loaded by Apache, the .php extension means absolutely nothing to the server.

Try to upload another file, called, say, info.php with only one line in it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and opening it in a browser. If it works, PHP is not the issue. If it doesn't, that's where your problem is.

Comment: This is the strange thing. I created a new file called test.php includ only "<?php phpinfo(); ?> ", saved in the same directory with index.php. The test.php works, but index.php doesn't.

Comment: It's a long shot, but are you using any plugins? If yes, how about trying to disable them?

Comment: Second question: Do you also have an `index.html` file in the root? If yes, delete it and try again. And a third: Does the index work when you try to open it by name (like `http://site.tld/index.php`)? If yes, then the `DirectoryIndex` is missing `index.php`

Comment: Do you mean disable plugins for Wordpress? Nothing changed

Comment: There is no index.html in the root. It got the same if using http://site.tld/index.php (ask to download)

Comment: I tried your link. It works, no download suggested. I guess you cleared your cache by now, but since it's the only difference between out browsers, how about giving it a try?

Comment: Well. It works. I was using InPrivate mode, not thinking this will result the such strange problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I've solved renaming the web folder in /var/www/ to another name and now  works fine.

I hope my experience be usefull for someone.